# git rebase with merge conflicts

Tags: git, github

```
       B
       |
       C - E -F my branch
       |
       D

    develop
    branch
```

my branch has two commits and merge conflicts, what the steps I should follow to rebase my branch and resolve conflicts.

Comment: Where do you have the merge conflict? Merging with the develop branch, or merging with your own upstream?

Comment: If you have merge conflict, you will probably also have conflict when doing a rebase.

Comment: merging with develop branch

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:

Start by rebasing your branch

```
git rebase develop
```

Then resolve the conflicts and add the file with conflicts

```
git add [fileWithConflictResolved]
```

Then git rebase continue to rebase the next commit

```
git rebase --continue
```

Repeat until the rebase is done

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to rebase `my branch` on `develop branch` and your `my branch` has two commits (**E** and **F**) that are not in your `develop branch`, so in order to completely rebase  `my branch` on `develop branch` git will try to replay the commits that are in `my branch` but not in `develop branch` (i.e. **E** and **F**) if no merge conflicts are there.

But since in your case git is seeing merge conflicts while trying to rebase, so you will have to resolve the conflicts twice(once for both **E** and **F**).

Basically if you are using git bash then you should be able to see something like `my branch | REBASE 1/2` in the place of branch name, which means git is trying to replay the first conflicting commit **E** and asking you to resolve the conflicts by deleting the conflict markers in your files appropriately.

Once you are done with resolving this first conflict as part of REBASE **1**/2, you then need to stage your changes via `git add` and continue to resolving the next conflict by executing `git rebase --continue`.

You should now see something like `my branch | REBASE 2/2` which means you now have to resolve the second conflicting commit **F** as part of REBASE **2**/2. Resolve the conflicts in your files again,  perform `git add` and then `git rebase --continue`.

You should a message similar to `Successfully rebased and updated refs/head/my branch`.

This means you have successfully rebased your `my branch` on top of `develop branch`.